# Rising Edge Counter

Tags: verilog, counter

I'm new to fpgas in general.  I want to make counter that iterates each time SCK sees a rising edge.  The issue i'm having with my code is that it seems to count twice.  Two leds are lit each time there is a rising edge transition - as opposed to just one led.  Any idea where this may be coming from?

```
module spi_slave(pcEn, LED, clk, SCK);
input clk, SCK;
output reg pcEn;
output reg [7:0] LED = 8'h00;
reg r1 = 0;
reg r2 = 0;
reg r3 = 0;
reg [3:0] cnt = 4'b0000;

always @(posedge clk) 
begin

    r1 <= SCK;              
    r2 <= r1;
    pcEn <= r1 && !r3;   
    if (pcEn == 1) begin
        cnt = cnt + 4'b0001;

        if (cnt == 4'b0001) begin
            LED[0] = 1'b1;  
            end
        else if (cnt == 4'b0010) begin
            LED[1] = 1'b1;  
            end
        else if (cnt == 4'b0011) begin
            LED[2] = 1'b1;  
            end
        else if (cnt == 4'b0100) begin
            LED[3] = 1'b1;      
            end
        else if (cnt == 4'b0101) begin
            LED[4] = 1'b1;      
            end
        else if (cnt == 4'b0110) begin
            LED[5] = 1'b1;  
            end
        else if (cnt == 4'b0111) begin
            LED[6] = 1'b1;  
            end
        else if (cnt == 4'b1000) begin
            LED[7] = 1'b1;  
            end
        else
            LED = 8'h00;
        end
    else 
        #100;

    r3 <= r2;
    end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

The counter is counting twice because you are comparing `r1 & !r3`.

r1->r2->r3 .it takes 2 clocks for r3 to be set after r1 equal 1. This implies that `r1&!r3` condition will remain valid for 2 clocks. The pcEn will be generated for 2 clocks , Hence the counter will count twice.

`r1 && !r2` or if you want a delay `r2 && !r3` should work fine.

you should be able to see this behavior in a waveform to debug.Use `$dumpvars;` in your simulation to view the waveform.

Also there are couple of change to improve the code.

1. use of reset.
2. consistently use non-blocking assignment .
3. there is no need for #100 delay.

   ```
   module spi_slave(pcEn, LED, clk, SCK,rst_n);
   input clk, SCK,rst_n;
   output reg pcEn;
   output reg [7:0] LED ;
   reg r1 ;
   reg r2 ;
   reg r3 ;
   reg [3:0] cnt ;

   always @(posedge clk or negedge rst_n)
   begin

      if ( rst_n == 0 )
      begin
           r1 <=0 ;
           r2 <= 0 ;
           r3 <= 0 ;
           cnt <= 0 ;
           LED <=0 ;
           pcEn <=0 ;
      end
      else
      begin
            r1 <= SCK;
            r2 <= r1;
            r3 <= r2;
            pcEn <= r2 && !r3;
            if (pcEn == 1) begin
                cnt <= cnt + 4'b0001;

                if (cnt == 4'b0001) begin
                    LED[0] <= 1'b1;
                    end
                else if (cnt == 4'b0010) begin
                    LED[1] <= 1'b1;
                    end
                else if (cnt == 4'b0011) begin
                    LED[2] <= 1'b1;
                    end
                else if (cnt == 4'b0100) begin
                    LED[3] <= 1'b1;
                    end
                else if (cnt == 4'b0101) begin
                    LED[4] <= 1'b1;
                    end
                else if (cnt == 4'b0110) begin
                    LED[5] <= 1'b1;
                    end
                else if (cnt == 4'b0111) begin
                    LED[6] <= 1'b1;
                    end
                else if (cnt == 4'b1000) begin
                    LED[7] <= 1'b1;
                    end
                else
                    LED <= 8'h00;
            end
      end
   end

   endmodule
   ```

Answer (score 1):

First of `#` delays are not synthesizable, they are delays for simulation only.

Generally is considered best practice to separate block and non-blocking logic into different always blocks. `always @*` for combinational (blocking assignments), and `always @(posedge clk)` for sequential (non-blocking assignments). FYI : Verilog supports case-statements which make coding value compare easier then nesting else-if.

I thing you may want to use `r2 && !r3` instead of `r1 && !r3` as Rahul also pointed out

```
always @* begin
  if (pcEn == 1'b0) begin
    next_cnt = cnt;
    next_LED = LED;
  else begin
    next_cnt = cnt + 4'b0001;
    next_LED = 8'h00; // Rest all to 0s
    if(cnt >= 8'h8) next_cnt = 4'b0000; // optional : assuming you want to roll back before waiting another 8 SCK toggles
    case(cnt)
    4'b0000 : next_LED[0] = 1'b1;
    4'b0001 : next_LED[1] = 1'b1;
    // ...
    4'b0111 : next_LED[7] = 1'b1;
    endcase
  end
end
always @(posedge clk) begin
  r1 <= SCK;
  r2 <= r1;
  r3 <= r2;
  pcEn <= r2 && !r3;
  cnt <= next_cnt;
  LED <= next_LED;
end
```